# get cutting points of histogram equalization - matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I'm trying to get the cutting points which were used for creating histogram equalization (by `histeq` or in another way), i.e. to get the original pixel values which were used to determine every bin edges.

In order to simplify the following example, I will use 1D matrix:

If the original image is: `[ 0.2 , 0.25 , 0.34 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 ]`

and the image after histogram equalization (to 3 bins) is: `[ 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 ]`

how do I get the edges of the 3 bins?

i.e. how do I get the following vector (which represent the cutting points):  `[0.37 0.5]` ?

Thanks a lot !!!

P.S. getting the vector `[0.34 0.4]` or `[0.4 0.6]` (Respectively, minimum and maximum values to be included in a specific bin after histeq) is also satisfying.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you possibly post here relevant parts of the code you already have (if any)?

Comment: Thanks!
The relevant code is very simple:
img_after_histeq = histeq(img,3);

Answer (score 0):

(If I got your question right) I could imagine to do something like the following:

```
dVec = diff(eqdata);
fVec = find(dVec);
cuttingPoints = eqdata(fVec) + dVec(fVec)/2;
```

Example:

```
eqdata =  [ 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.2 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 ];
```

Output:

```
0.3000    0.5000
```

Edit: In case of unsorted data:

```
dVec = diff(sort(unique(eqdata)));
fVec = find(dVec);
cuttingPoints = eqdata(fVec) + dVec(fVec)/2;
```

Comment: but I think my example wasn't general enough. Another example: [0.6 , 0.1 , 0.3 , 0.34 , 0.5 , 0.12] ---- histeq (3 bin) ---> [0.6 , 0.1 , 0.35 , 0.35 , 0.6 , 0.1] ---- get cutting points ---> [0.21 , 0.42] BTW, getting the cutting points [0.12 , 0.34] or [0.3 , 0.5] is also good enough

Comment: @sob I do not exactly understand you. Where shall I in your example know from that it is based on `0.21` and not on `(0.1+0.35)/2 = 0.225` as I would expect?

Comment: it is based on 0.21 (and not on 0.225) because: (0.12+0.3)/2 = 0.21.  Note that 0.12 is the maximum original value which was mapped to the 1st level (1st level=0.1), and 0.3 is the minimum original value which was mapped to the 2st level (2st level=0.35). Please look at my edited original question :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that will be suitable for both vectors and matrices (sorted or unsorted). It uses the `unique` and  `median` functions.

You will have the intermediate values (here using `median`) in-between bin values. You will also have the bin index to which each image element was assigned to.

The following code

```
%data
A = [ 0.2 , 0.25 , 0.34 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.4 , 0.6 , 0.6 , 0.6 ]; % vector
%A = rand(5,5); % matrix (other possible input)
bin_number = 3;    

%histogram
J = histeq(A,bin_number); %histogram equalization
[Ju, ia, ic] = unique(J(:)); %uniquing

%values of in-between bins (here using median)
cutting_index = median([Ju(1:end-1) Ju(2:end)]');

%get the assignment
assign_index = reshape(ic,size(A));
```

will produce

```
cutting_index = [0.2500    0.7500]
assign_index = [1     1     1     2     2     2     3     3     3]'
```

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, but I guess that I should have been more clear:

Comment: I wanted to know what is the range of values in which a pixel (in the original image) should be included, so it will be mapped to a certain bin after histogram equalization. If we look in my original example, my goal was to know that if a pixel value in the original image was in the range [0 , 0.37), than it was mapped to the 1st bin. if a pixel value in the original image was in the range [0.37 , 0.5), than it was mapped to the 2nd bin. if a pixel value in the original image was in the range [0.5 , 0.6], than it was mapped to the 3rd bin.

Comment: Please see my edits. You will have the unique bin values in `Ju`, in-between bin values in `cutting_index`, and the bin assignment in `assign_index`.

Comment: Wow, that's nice! but why do you have 4 (instead of 3) bins in assign_index ?

Comment: BTW, can you tell me how do you add this gray background to variable names in your comment? I'm new here :)

Comment: just use ` signs around what you want to write in code style :-)

Comment: My response is edited - I forgot to edit the output during the last edit - sorry for the confusion - there is three bins. As @matheburg wrote, the comment's format is easy to manipulate and explained [in this meta-SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24793/how-to-use-formatting-in-comments). Finally, please don't forget to accept the answer that suits you the best as it might be of help for future readers (if any), and reward the effort SO users put in answering your question by voting up their contribution.